# I can't build a specific request in the repository with querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I have 3 tables "**User**", "**Events**" an "**typeEvents**" I would like to get a list of user with one where (ex : type = "Festival").
As well user entity is in another bundle that Events and typeEvents. but this is not the problem.

In one of Entity, I have a manyToMany relationship...so I can't do this query builder request.

**User.php :**

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pseudo", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $events
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\Events", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     */
    private $events;
    [...]
```

**Events.php:**

```
class Events
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TypeEvents", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $typeEvents;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GenreEvents", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $genreEvents;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $user;
    [...]
```

**TypeEvents.php:**

```
class TypeEvents
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $events
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Events", mappedBy="typeEvents", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     */
    private $events;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $type;
    [...]
```

So in the userRepository I'm trying with :

```
public function findUserEvent()
    {
        $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->leftJoin('u.events', 'ev')
            ->addSelect('ev')
            ->where('BISSAPBenevolesBundle:TypeEvents.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', 'Festival')
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

And I get this error : `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 78 near 'BISSAPBenevolesBundle:TypeEvents.type': Error: 'BISSAPBenevolesBundle:TypeEvents' is not defined.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
public function findUserEvent()
    {
        $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->leftJoin('u.events', 'ev')
            ->leftJoin('ev.types', 'evt')
            ->where('evt.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', 'Festival')
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Hope this help